# Extending ASP.NET MVC Controller with redirection or 404 error in certain circumstances

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, overriding

I want to extend the Controller class to check whether a request matches certain criteria.
In particular, I want to check whether the user has been directed from a certain URL using the UrlReferrer proprety.

If the user has not come from a particular URL, it should return a 404 message, or in some cases redirect to a different URL altogether.

I was overriding OnActionExecuting to look like this:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!IsAuthenticRequest())
        {
            return new HttpNotFoundResult();
            //or in some cases I want to redirect to a completely different URL.

        }
    }
```

But this does not work because its a void method.

How would I go about performing this task?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the other answer is correct, I don't think it's a good solution for your scenario. I think what you need is a custom Action Filter like this:

```
public class MyActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!IsAuthenticRequest())
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpNotFoundResult();
        }
    }    
}
```

Then, you can use this filter either at the Controller level (to apply it to all Actions in the Controller) or at the Action level:

```
[MyActionFilter]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
}
```

Comment: In this case, how would you go about getting Request.UrlReferrer in the Request object within the ActionFilterAttribute?

Comment: Use `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer`.

Comment: Found it! filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a void method, but inside the `filterContext` parameter you have a `Result` property. If the result is filled by the time the `OnActionExecuting` method finishes, the actual Action method is not even going to be called.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (!IsAuthenticRequest())
    {
        filterContext.Result = new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want this behavior to be consistent across different controllers, you might want to consider writing a `filter` instead. To understand more about it, please refer to: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Answer (score 0):

I've just finished implementing a feature such as this within our primary intranet application.  My solution was to create a custom authorize filter as suggested by ataravati above,but to redirect according to certain circumstances.

```
public class UrCustomFilter:ActionFilterAttribute
{
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!IsAuthenticRequest())
        {
             if( cond1 == true)
                 filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Error" }, {"action", "404NotFound" } });
              else{
                  //do another redirect here 
              }
        }
    }
}
```